# Prevent tmux from starting up on SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, tmux

I would like `tmux` to create a new-window when I ssh onto a machine from an existing tmux session. However, I do not want a tmux session started on the new machine!

I have the following in my `.bashrc`, so that `tmux` automatically starts up:

```
if [[ "$TERM" != "screen" ]]
then
   # try to attach to existing session, or start a new one
   tmux attach-session -t "$USER" || tmux -2 new-session -s "$USER"
   exit
fi
```

I also have an `ssh` function:

```
alias ssh='ssh_func'
ssh_func (){
    if [[ "$TERM" == "screen" ]]; then
        tmux new-window -n "$1" "ssh $@";
    else
        /usr/bin/ssh "$@";
    fi
}
```

This works ok, but I do not want a tmux session started on the machine I ssh to, because this gives me 2 sessions in the same terminal window. Is there anything I can put in my `.bashrc` so that tmux does not start up on a machine if the ssh command has been invoked from a tmux session?

I am using PuTTY and tmux 1.5.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements. If you run ssh from within tmux, you'll have `$TERM = screen`, so you won't be trying to attach to a tmux window. How does that differ from what you want?

Comment: If I ssh from tmux I don't get `TERM=screen`. I get `TERM=linux`. It doesn't seem to get exported.

Comment: If you get a different value of `TERM` after ssh'ing, there's something wrong with your setup. As far as I can tell the code you posted should do what you want on a normal setup. You need to investigate what is mangling `$TERM`. Do you have any code that sets it in `~/.ssh/*` or in `~/.*` or in `/etc/*`?

Comment: @Gilles you're right. I was setting TERM in one of my dotfiles. Removing it has worked. Please add this as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code you've posted, if you run ssh from within tmux, you'll have `$TERM` = `screen`, so you won't be trying to attach to a tmux window. In other words, the code you already have should work as desired. There's something fishy going on. Make sure your dot files don't mess up the `TERM` variable (if you need to modify `TERM`, which is very rare, make sure to do it only in very specific circumstances; in particular don't change it if it's `screen`).

Answer (score 1):

You can test for presence of the `SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable: if that variable is defined then the shell has been started from SSH.  For example:

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]; then
  # running within SSH session, do not start tmux
  ...
else
  # logged in from console/terminal, start tmux
  tmux ...
fi
```

The variable contains four space-separated values: client IP address,
client port number, server IP address, and server port number.
You can use this for more complex matching, e.g.:

```
case "$SSH_CONNECTION" in
  client.ip.v4.addr*)
   # client is client.ip.v4.addr != this host's addr
   echo "you're connecting from a remote host, starting tmux"
   tmux ...
   ;;
  *server.ip.v4.addr)
   # if server.ip.v4.addr == this hosts' address, then SSH_CONNECTION
   # is not inherited from another connection
   echo "SSH_CNNECTION is not stale"
   ;;
  '') 
   # no SSH_CONNECTION at all
   ;;
esac
```

More details on the `SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable in the
"ENVIRONMENT" section of the [ssh(1) manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh).

Comment: This won't work for me because I always use ssh to log on to an initial machine from PuTTY, so my `SSH_CONNECTION` is always set. I need to somehow detect if the ssh was invoked from within a tmux session.

Comment: You can then match on the *actual contents* of `SSH_CONNECTION`, not just its presence.  I've edited the answer with an example.